# Centralizer of product of two elements as the intersection of centralizer of each

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a finite non-abelian group. Let $x, y$ be two non-central and mutually commuting elements in $G$ such that $C_G(x) = C_G(y).$ Then under what conditions can we say that $C_G(xy) = C_G(x) = C_G(y)?$

The only thing that I am able to see is that we always have $C_G(x) \ \cap \ C_G(y) \subseteq C_G(xy).$ What can be said about the reverse inclusion in the given scenario that $C_G(x) = \ C_G(y)$?

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: The question is trivial if $G$ is abelian.

Comment: For any group $G$, $C_G(x)=C_G(x^{-1})$, and $C_G(xx^{-1})=G$.  So if $x\notin Z(G)$, then $C_G(xx^{-1})\not\subseteq C_G(x)$.

Comment: I am asking about the non-trivial cases, of course. I have edited the question accordingly.

Comment: The question is too general.
Here is one of the conditions.
Let $G$ be some group, let $H$ be a maximal subgroup of $G$.
Let $Z(G)=\{e\}$, $|Z(H)|\geq3$.
For any $z\in Z(H)$, $z\neq e$ we obtain that $C_G(z)=H$.
Hence, if $x,y\in Z(H)$ and $x,y,xy\neq e$ then $C_G(x)=C_G(y)=C_G(xy)=H$.

Comment: Here $C_G(x)=C_G(y)$, denote this by $H$; then what you can see that $x,y$ are *central in $H$*, so $xy$ is also central in $H$, and hence $C_G(xy)\supset H=C_G(x)$. If $x,y$ are of co-prime order, then the equality should hold. But, if $x,y$ are not of co-prime order, say you work in $p$-groups, it is not so easy to tell, under what condition, $C_G(xy)$ will be equal to $C_G(x)$.